# how to convert string to int in objective c

Tags: iphone

i am trying to display annotations in map.
I have the lat and longi in string format.
now i just need to convert it to int.

```
    NSString *s= @"18.65799";
    location1.latitude =[s intValue];
    NSLog(@"1%d",[s intValue]);
            NSString *s1= @"73.774262";
    location1.longitude=[s1 intValue];
```

But when i display [s intValue]the out put is 118.
and output for NSLog(@"1%@",location1.latitude) is null;

Please  help.

Comment: 10 questions, and 18 answers among them...

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
NSLog(@"1%d",[s intValue]);
```

to:

```
NSLog(@"%d", [s intValue]);
```

Similarly for s1:

```
NSLog(@"%d", [s1 intValue]);
```